# Select a number of items of each type

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So my SQL table looks like this:

```
EVENTS
#id
*event_type
```

I want to select 5 items of each type without making 5 sepparate queries and making a union. Is there any method?

Comment: What is your expected criteria to select those 5 items?

Answer (score 1):

In order to limit the result to 5 items per group you should use a limit clause in a subquery. My current version of MySQL doesn't allow that to happen (5.1.47) I'm not sure if this is supported in newer versions.

This is the closest I can get:

```
select id, event_type from events e1
where (
    select count(*) from events e2
    where e1.event_type = e2.event_type) >= 5;
```

This will return for the pair id, event_type for all event_types that have 5 or more ids associated.

The other query I thought of was the one I mentioned I couln't run because I was getting:

```
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

I'm not sure if any version supports it or if it is a misleading error. Here is the theorical query:

```
select id, event_type from events e1
where (
    select count(*) from events e2
    where (
    e2.id in (
        select id from events e3
        where e3.event_type = e2.event_type
        limit 5
    ) and e2.event_type = e1.event_type)
) >= 5;
```

I'm pretty sure if mysql could handle that limit there it would work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try it as soon as I get home, indeed old mySQL versions have some limitations, but I recall doing a subquery in a WHERE IN sometime ago and it worked, so the second example should be functional.

Answer (score -1):

try to use aggregate functions :

```
SELECT event_type,max(id) FROM `EVENTS` GROUP BY event_type
```

Comment: The max(id) is not needed in MySQL, just `id` will resolve faster and be almost as indeterminate, +1 for grokking the question.

Comment: This is a bit away from the expected result, as the OP expects to receive 5 IDs per each event_type and this results in only one

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
select id, event_type 
from EVENTS e 
where (
    select count(*) 
    from EVENTS e1 where e.event_type=e1.event_type and e1.id < e.id) < 5 
order by event_type;
```

Comment: What is the reason for downvoting?  I think this code works fine.